# Setting Domain Bounds while performing KDE with Scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I've implemented a KDE program to perform density estimation using the scikit package class `sklearn.neighbors.DensityEstimation`.

The program works properly, but it seems to assume the domain bounds to be within the observed range (for example, if the minimum and maximum observed ages are 15 and 75, the domain should still be 0-100, not 15-75).

How can I change the domain bounds of a `sklearn.neighbors.DensityEstimation` instance?